Inconsistent behavior between Python function and VS Code debugger for scope lookup
For the following code (revised):
# infile.py

FILE1 = 'file1'
FILE2 = 'file2'

def getfile():
    # Note:  I am doing the equivalent of this with VS Code debugger:
    # breakpoint()
    file = FILE1 if 'FILE1' in locals() else FILE2
    print(f'{file=}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getfile()

If I run this on Windows (using Python 3.12.7 or Python 3.13.0), here's what I see:
PS> .\infile.py
file='file2'

If I run this in my VS Code debugger (v1.95.3, Python v2024.20.0, Pylance v2024.12.1, Python Debugger v2024.12.0), here's what I see:
# Uncomment breakpoint at first line in above def getfile function
# Start VS Code in debugging mode (F5)
# VS Code stops at breakpoint
# From VS Code Debug Console, execute following:
file = FILE1 if 'FILE1' in locals() else FILE2

print(f'{file=})

# Output:
file='file1'

My expectation was the result shown in the VS Code debugger above.  It sounds like I'm not quite understanding something with Python scoping.  What am I missing?
I'm also curious why I see a difference between what Python does and what the VS Code Python debugger shows.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?
Revised:
If I do this with pdb, I see this:
PS> .\infile
> ...\infile.py(9)getfile()
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) l
  4     FILE1 = 'file1'
  5     FILE2 = 'file2'
  6
  7
  8     def getfile():
  9  ->     breakpoint()
 10         file = FILE1 if 'FILE1' in locals() else FILE2
 11         # file = FILE1 if 'FILE1' in globals() else FILE2
 12         print(f'{file=}')
 13
 14
(Pdb) 'FILE1' in locals()
False
(Pdb) 'FILE1' in globals()
True
(Pdb)

So, I think what I really want is to use globals() - is that right?

In your second code sample you don't show the function which is relevant to the problem.

Why did you expect print(file) to have the same result as print(f'{file=}')? The first prints the value of file, which is 'file1' because you're executing in the same local scope where FILE1 and FILE2 were defined (not in a function), and the second prints 'file=', followed by the value of file,  which is file2, due to the definitions of FILE1 and FILE2 not being in the local scope. Have a look at the documentation for locals() - calling it in a function won't include definitions from the surrounding scope.

By the way, whatever reason you have to be messing around with locals(), it's almost certain there's a better way to achieve what you're really trying to do. It's very common for beginning programmers to go down the rabbit hole of messing with locals and globals, when they really need to learn about function parameters and returned results.

@Grismar I revised my question.  When I use the debugger in VS Code (hopefully the revised question clarifies what I'm doing), locals() includes FILE1 and FILE2.  However, when I use it in pdb it does not.  Sounds like I want globals.  I did check the locals() documentation, I wasn't clear if it showed globals or not since I believe Python scoping rules are LEGB, so globals are "accessible" from a function.

@KlausD. I revised my question - hopefully that clarifies things.

@Grismar Fair point with using locals/globals.  I'm doing code challenges which are cloud hosted.  I prefer to solve them locally and use my own setup.  When I push the solution back to the cloud I use their setup.  This is a hack so I can use the same function whether its either my local setup or the cloud setup.  The program is completely different - this is just capturing the essence of the issue.  So, you're saying locals() only returns the L part of LEGB.  That makes sense - thanks for the clarification.

Which code challenges? I've done many on many sites and don't see a need/use for this hack. Actually... what of that even is the hack? And what does that have to do with the debugger? Seems like the XY problem now.

@nocomment Thanks for the reply.  I tried to explain what I'm doing and why below.  What was interesting to me with the debugger is why I appear to get different behavior for locals() depending on whether I use the VS Code Python debugger or pdb.  When I posted the question, I wasn't clear on the behavior of locals() - my intent was not to promote an approach.  I would welcome suggestions on how to tackle the cloud code challenges in a better fashion if you'd care to leave another comment.  If it helps, the challenges are Pybites.

Based on what @Grismar said, it sounds like the answer is that the locals() built-in function only shows things defined in the local scope.  In other words, if we define Python scoping as LEGB, locals() only displays the "L" part.  For what I was trying to do, I need to use the globals() built-in.
As for VS Code, it appears that when using the Python debugger in VS Code that locals() displays more than just the "L" scope.  However, I believe pdb is the definitive debugger and that only shows things in the "L" scope.
Finally - is what I'm trying to do a good idea?  Maybe/maybe not.  In a nutshell - I'm doing Cloud hosted code challenges.  The cloud environment defines their own variables (globals) that make sense for them (a Linux hosted environment).  I choose to solve the challenges locally on a Windows environment.  My environment is quite a bit different, so I define my own variables that make sense for my environment.  I want to do something generic that works in either environment, so I check if my variable is defined.  If yes use it, if no fallback to the cloud definition.  There's probably a better way to do this and I'm open to suggestions.
In terms of what I'm trying to do - here is an example code challenge skeleton that I hope is illustrative:
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Cloud Environment - temporary (throw away):
TEMPFILE = os.getenv('TMP', '/tmp')
FNAME = 'data.csv'
LOCALFILE = os.path.join(TMP, FNAME)

# My Environment - in a local repo I wish to keep:
CWD = Path(__file__).parent
DATADIR = CWD/'data'
DATA = CWD/DATADIR/FNAME

# Why this approach instead of just setting a default
# parameter or specifying DATA as a parameter which invoking
# the function?
# Because I want to copy this function as is back to the
# cloud hosted challenge - this only changes things if
# my variables are defined.  In addition, the cloud environment
# comes with tests that need to run unchanged to validate the
# solution.  The prevents me from changing the function
# invocation parameter.
def code_challenge(targetfile):
    targetfile = DATA if 'DATA' in globals() else LOCALFILE
    ...

If this is the wrong approach, please share example code of the right way to do it.
Thanks again for all the feedback.
